# How to upgrade Linux version without breaking the original settings or configs?

Tags: linux, upgrade

I want to upgrade my linux version to an upper level, but I am afraid of by doing that, it will format the original settings or configs on my machine. So is there any way that we can avoid this happen?

Comment: Do you want to upgrade your version of the kernel, or of your distro?

Comment: it will affect both the disto and kernel I think.

Comment: Which distribution are you running?

Comment: I am going to upgrade from 5.03 to 5.50, it will definately upgrade my kernel as well, right?

Comment: There is no Linux 5.03. The latest version is 3.11-rc1. See https://www.kernel.org for details. Otoh, if you meant a linux distribution, retag this question.

Comment: If you're running distribution from Debian family (Ubuntu, Mint), this text could be of help for you. It describes, how dpkg handles your manual settings in configuration files: http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot of information here, for instance you haven't mentioned how you're going to be upgrading (does your distro provide a dedicated upgrade tool or are you just going to run the installer of the new version?) or what type of version jump your making (for instance *buntu 9.04 to 13.04 is going to be a lot more painful than, say, 12.10 to 13.04). You also haven't mentioned how your partitions are set up, whether you've got your `/etc`, `/usr`, `/home`, and `/srv` directories on their own partition, or you've just got one huge `/`, but seen as though you specifically mention configs & settings here is some **very general** advice.

There are probably three things that you care about. Your system-wide configs, your user configs, your servables, and possibly your installed packages. System-wide config is usually all found under `/etc`. Upgrade tools and the more clever installers will be nice to your `/etc`, preserving your existing config files where possible, and prompting you to manually resolve conflicts. However, some installers won't or can't go out of their way to look after your existing configs, but the good news is that `/etc` is easily back-upable (mine, for instance, comes to <18mb on quite an old install).

Your user config will be stored (usually hidden as dotfiles) in your user's home directory. So, for example, if the same `.kde` directory exists in your home folder, then your KDE should look and behave exactly as it did before the upgrade. There's no reason any installer should be writing to `/home`. 
For your servables, it is probably going to be necessary (but would have always been recommended, anyway) to back these up. Make sure you think of everything you are serving and you get them all. You may have to do some Googling to find out where your distro puts things by default. Say you have some web content and some MySQL databases, if you're lucky these will be under `/srv/www` and `/srv/mysql`, but it's quite common to find your web stuff under `/var/www`, and your MySQL databases somewhere strange under `/var/lib`.

The thing I'd be most concerned about is the partitioning stage of your install. If your `/home` isn't on it's' own partition, then if you format `/` you will lose everything. However, not formatting can leave a lot of garbage lying around, especially for large version jumps, and may leave your system unstable. You're going to have to think about the risk is worth the hassle of a full backup.

Comment: Thanks Poundex. You mean that those applications & configurations that I have installed will need to be redone after the Linux upgrade, as most applications will require a new version as well, and their associated configuration files usually change with new versions. I will think about the hassle of a full backup and upgrade. Thanks!